# include elements that users cannot remove

Tags: templates, include, mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

How do I include elements such as the {{seo:}} tag such that it cannot be seen and or removed by a user editing the page contents?

I've looked at the templates, page forms, other extensions, etc. but I didn't see a way to accomplish this.

Comment: Why do you make it a part of wikitext if you don't want users to see and remove it?

Comment: You should use PHP: some extension or `LocalSettings.php`.